# Delete rows in data frame based on condition of ranked values

Tags: pandas

if i have the below dataframe

```
raw_data = {
'code': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
'Date': ['2022-01-04','2022-01-01', '2022-01-03','2022-01-02', '2022-01-08', '2022-01-07','2022-01-06','2022-01-05'],
'flag_check': [np.NaN, np.NaN, '11-33-24-33333' ,np.NaN, np.NaN,'11-55-24-33443' ,np.NaN, np.NaN],
'rank':[np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=['code', 'Date','flag_check', 'rank'])
```

I need to do the following

1- rank the entries based on code then date

2- within the same code entries fill the rank column with series numbers 1,2,3 based on the code and the date.

3- check the value of a "flag_check" if it is not null then delete all rows after it

Expected result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

```py
df['rank'] = df.groupby(['code'])['Date'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
df = df.sort_values(['code','Date'])
x = df.groupby('code')['flag_check'].apply(lambda x:x.shift().notna().cumsum())
df = df.loc[x[x==0].index,:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Input:

```
   code        Date      flag_check  rank
0     1  2022-01-04             NaN   NaN
1     1  2022-01-01             NaN   NaN
2     1  2022-01-03  11-33-24-33333   NaN
3     1  2022-01-02             NaN   NaN
4     2  2022-01-08             NaN   NaN
5     2  2022-01-07  11-55-24-33443   NaN
6     2  2022-01-06             NaN   NaN
7     2  2022-01-05             NaN   NaN
```

Output:

```
   code        Date      flag_check  rank
0     1  2022-01-01             NaN     1
1     1  2022-01-02             NaN     2
2     1  2022-01-03  11-33-24-33333     3
3     2  2022-01-05             NaN     1
4     2  2022-01-06             NaN     2
5     2  2022-01-07  11-55-24-33443     3
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Annotated code

```
# Order by Date
s = df.sort_values('Date')

# rank the date column per code group
s['rank'] = s.groupby('code')['Date'].rank(method='dense')

# create boolean mask to identify the rows after the first non-null value
mask = s['flag_check'].notna()[::-1].groupby(df['code']).cummax()
```

##### Result

```
s[mask]

   code        Date      flag_check  rank
1     1  2022-01-01             NaN   1.0
3     1  2022-01-02             NaN   2.0
2     1  2022-01-03  11-33-24-33333   3.0
7     2  2022-01-05             NaN   1.0
6     2  2022-01-06             NaN   2.0
5     2  2022-01-07  11-55-24-33443   3.0
```